# Custom foreign key in EF Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Someone please help me to resolve this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'DataLayer.Data.SETTINGGRP' and 'DataLayer.Data.SETTING'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

My code:

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public long objectId { get; set; }    
}

public partial class SETTINGGRP: BaseEntity
{  
    public string REMARKS { get; set; } 
    public virtual SETTING SETTING { get; set; }
}

public partial class SETTING : BaseEntity
{ 
    public Nullable<long> SETTINGGRP_objectId { get; set; } 
    public string NAME { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("SETTINGGRP_objectId")]
    public virtual SETTINGGRP SETTINGGRP { get; set; } 
}
```

I have referred this url: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToRequired

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<WORKERINFO>().HasKey(d => new { d.objectId, d.EMP_objectId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<WORKERINFO>().HasRequired(t => t.EMP).WithOptional(t => t.WORKERINFO);
    }
```

I want objectId to be the primary key and SETTINGGRP_objectId should be the foreign key.

Please suggest me how to write annotation or fluent api.

Comment: Why EF4 and not EF6?

Comment: @abatishchev I am using EF6

Comment: Ok, you've tagged with ef4, I revised.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems that `SETTINGGRP` and `SETTING` are in one-to-one relationship. If that is the case, you might need to configure the relationship. To do the same, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToRequired.

However, intuitively (from the name of entities) it seems that the relation should be one-to-many, i.e. one `SETTINGGRP` has many `SETTING`s (however, I might be wrong), and in that case, I think only changing the `SETTING` property in `SETTINGGRP` in following way, will do the trick:

```
public virtual ICollection<SETTING> SETTINGS { get; set; }
```

> I want objectId to be the primary key and SETTINGGRP_objectId should be the foreign key.

For this, try to use [Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.6), and then use `HasKey()`, and `HasForeignKey()` to specify the primary key, and foreign key properties.